# jQuery AJAX - Display responses HTML as a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax in this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        if ( foo ) {               
            alert("foo happened");
            // do stuff
        } else if (bar) {        
            // ??? display response as page ???
        }
    },
    error: { .... }
    }
});
```

Basically, in case of "foo" I do some ajax stuff on the page, but in case of "bar" I receive a fully-formed page that I simply want to display as-is. As if, basically, I had just clicked a submit button and the browser just did its normal thing with the response received from the server.... Any jQuery/JavaScript function to do that?

In other words, how I can just sort of "forward" the response to the browser so that it gets treated by it normally?

Comment: Hi ! Why not simply create a new `node` in an existing `div` and populate it with the html content you received ?

Comment: Well,  it's mostly that I have existing code server-side that returns me a full page with all the stuff I need. I could do as @Serge mentionned below. THough that will need a bit of refactoring I guess/extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using ajax you can't refresh the whole page, you can only refresh the partial view that should be defined inside of the main view . if you try to return the whole you will get a layout with it too

```
<div id="myPartialView">
  @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView",Model)
 </div>
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
        
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
            type: "POST",
            data: {myData:myData}
            success: function (result) {
                    $("#myPartialView").html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
               
            }
        });
```

and the action

```
public partial class MyController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult MyAction(MyData myData)
  {
      ... some code
      var model = new myModel { ... assign model properties  };
     return PartialView("_MyPartialView", model);
 }
}
```

PS.

if you don' t use MVC you still should have this html

```
<div id="myPartialView">
  
 </div>
```

but ajax will be the same.

Comment: Ah I think see. Using django but could do similar there. E.g. structure things so that my endpoint server-side returns the html for just the partials sections (which in my case would be some form). Then on the client side, append the html to the container of that partial (or those partials if I have a few sections).

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions Yes, you are right I updated my answer.